# Special characters in CSS selector

Tags: css, special-characters

I found this CSS definition in the [semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/). They use this style extensively.

```
.ui.\32.buttons > .button,
.ui.two.buttons > .button {
  width: 50%;
}
```

I can see what they are trying to accomplish.
They want the CSS definition to read

```
.ui.2.buttons > .button,
```

It must be ASCII code. Code \32 would be a space. Code \3 would be a "start of text".

Can you explain more what is going on here? Why is the ascii not converted into a space?
And why does the [W3C CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) accept this CSS without errors?

Comment: They even use `.ui.\31\32.buttons > .button`. I'd be really curious to see what this is doing.

Comment: Technically, class names aren't supposed to start with a digit, so `.2` would be an error. (In practice, browsers don't really seem to mind though.) By the way, it's a hexadecimal number, not decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\32` is *hexadecimal* 32, which translates to decimal number 50, which is indeed the character `2`. `\31` would be `1`.

I found this quote from the W3C specs:

> In CSS2, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [A-Za-z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters 161 and higher, plus the hyphen (-); they cannot start with
>   a hyphen or a digit. They can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier “B&W?” may be written as “B\&W\?” or “B\26 W\3F”.

I found the quote in [this arcticle](http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/using_numbers_as_css_class_or_id_values) which puts it in context, but it boils down to the fact that although normally class names cannot start with a number, it is allowed when the number is entered as an escaped character or (in this case) an [ISO 10646 numeric code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set) for a character.

Comment: That's exactly what I was assuming, yet couldn't find evidence for! Thumbs up!